# Canonicalizing domain name with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I had a working `.htaccess` for my website, but I decided to add domain name canonicalization - e.g. prepend 'www' if it is omitted.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/$0 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
// etc
```

The first condition/rule are the ones I added. The second rule redirects empty filepath to "blog/". Now, the problem is, if I type in a path like "domain.com/page", for some reason it redirects me to the blog. If I change the first rule to `http://www.domain.com/test?url=$0`, it correctly redirects me to `www.domain.com/test?url=page`. What am I doing wrong, and is there a way to possibly see some sort of logs/debug output? (I'm using shared hosting so I don't have access to low level logs)

**Update:** its working fine now; it seems the redirects were cached somewhere, even though clearing all browser data didn't help. Could it be possible that the redirects got cached on proxy level, and how to deal with it, since it makes editing/debugging .htaccess nearly impossible?

Comment: You don't use $0 in htaccess, it should be $1. It starts from 1

Comment: Back-references are identifiers of the form $N (N=0..9), which will be replaced by the contents of the Nth group of the matched Pattern. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.